# How to grab string between two keywords in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, php-5.3

Not sure if this has been answered before - how can I grab string between two keywords?

For instance the string between a '**story**' and a '**?**',

```
http://mywebsie.com/hello/blog/story/archieve/2012/5/?page=1    
http://mywebsie.com/blog/story/archieve/2012/4/?page=1
http://mywebsie.com/blog/story/archieve/2012/?page=4
```

I just want,

```
story/archieve/2012/5/
story/archieve/2012/4/
story/archieve/2012/
```

**EDIT:**

If I use `parse_url`,

```
$string = parse_url('http://mywebsie.com/blog/story/archieve/2012/4/?page=1');
echo $string_uri['path'];
```

I get,

```
/blog/story/archieve/2012/4/
```

but I don't want to include '**blog/**'

Comment: To clarify, in the result you want to include the first keyword and exclude the second?

Comment: only want to include the first keyword not the second... sorry this is not very good thinking...

Comment: Added an answer, see if that fits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is safe to assume that the substrings you are looking for occur exactly once in the input string:

```
function getInBetween($string, $from, $to) {
    $fromAt = strpos($string, $from);
    $fromTo = strpos($string, $to);

    // if the upper limit is found before the lower
    if($fromTo < $fromAt) return false;

    // if the lower limit is not found, include everything from 0th
    // you may modify this to just return false
    if($fromAt === false) $fromAt = 0;

    // if the upper limit is not found, include everything up to the end of string
    if($fromTo === false) $fromTo = strlen($string);

    return substr($string, $fromAt, $fromTo - $fromAt);
}

echo getInBetween("http://mywebsie.com/hello/blog/story/archieve/2012/5/?page=1", "story", '?'); // story/archieve/2012/5/
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I got this errro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in...` refer to this line - `if($fromTo === false) $fromTo = strlen($string);`

Answer (score 2):

Another very simple way is we can create a simple function that can be invoked at any time.

```
<?php
  // Create the Function to get the string
  function GetStringBetween ($string, $start, $finish) {
  $string = " ".$string;
  $position = strpos($string, $start);
  if ($position == 0) return "";
  $position += strlen($start);
  $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
  return substr($string, $position, $length);
  }
?>
```

and here's an example usage for your question

```
$string1="http://mywebsie.com/hello/blog/story/archieve/2012/5/?page=1";    
$string2="http://mywebsie.com/blog/story/archieve/2012/4/?page=1";
$string3="http://mywebsie.com/blog/story/archieve/2012/?page=4";

echo GetStringBetween ($string1, "/blog/", "?page");
//result : story/archieve/2012/5/

echo GetStringBetween ($string2, "/blog/", "?page");
//result : story/archieve/2012/4/

echo GetStringBetween ($string3, "/blog/", "?page");
//result : story/archieve/2012/
```

For more detail please read http://codetutorial.com/howto/how-to-get-of-everything-string-between-two-tag-or-two-strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_url()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$parts = parse_url('http://mywebsie.com/story/archieve/2012/4/?page=1');
echo $parts['path'];
```

You can use `explode()` or whatever you need from there.

Comment: @lauthiamkok, Right, you can use `explode($parts['path'], '/', 2)` or something.  Split the path however you need.

Comment: thanks brad. `explode($parts['path'], '/', 2)` is targeting at a fix location. what about if I have something more before 'blog/' like 'hello/blog/'?

Comment: @lauthiamkok, Then you will need to modify your code.  I don't know exactly what you are trying to use as a delimiter.  You can use whatever you want.  If you're just looking for specific strings, you can use `strpos()` and `substr()` to get what you need.